# Awk to align output into column from lines

Tags: awk, printing

Here is the input data changed as shelter suggest. Pls support if now can be process or not

```
> Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 OPER=RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=511a3f0345bb4030acfccdb7b7d308b6,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
```

TRIED AGAIN

```
    awk 'BEGIN {
        HCNT = split("OPER|usr|description|req|TMUnitTroup|SUBTNode", COLN, "|")
        TMP = split("40 40 40 18 10 14 23", FLEN, FS)
        FMT = "%-*.*s "
        for (i = 1; i <= HCNT; i++) {
                printf FMT, FLEN[i], FLEN[i], COLN[i]
        }
        printf "Count" ORS
}

{
        OUT = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= HCNT; i++) {
                match($0, COLN[i] "[^ ]*")
                TMP = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
                sub(/^[^ ,]*= /, _, TMP)
                OUT = OUT sprintf(FMT, FLEN[i], FLEN[i], TMP)
        }
        T[OUT]++
}

END {
        for (t in T) {
                print t, T[t]
        }
}' tudberr
OPER                                     usr                                      description                              req                TMUnitTrou SUBTNode       Count
```

I wish this time my awk code readable .Here is the input file

```
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]: tons=1012 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER tag=101 usr=80 nentries=0 description=Read usror on tonsection to target req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp filter=(objectClass=*)
```

I need below output generated by reading above file . The output should be in columns as below to summaries this log.

```
  op      usr description                        req       TMUnitTroup SUBTNode COUNT
RESERCH 80  Read usror on tonsection to target serv=psts 10          21       6
```

I tried below code but output not exactly as i needed

```
    awk 'BEGIN {
        HCNT = split("op|usr|description|req|TMUnitTroup|SUBTNode", COLN, "|")
        TMP = split("40 40 40 18 10 14 23", FLEN, FS)
        FMT = "%-*.*s "
        for (i = 1; i <= HCNT; i++) {
                printf FMT, FLEN[i], FLEN[i], COLN[i]
        }
        printf "Count" ORS
}

{
        OUT = ""
        for (i = 1; i <= HCNT; i++) {
                match($0, COLN[i] "[^ ]*")
                TMP = substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH)
                sub(/^[^ ,]*= /, _, TMP)
                OUT = OUT sprintf(FMT, FLEN[i], FLEN[i], TMP)
        }
        T[OUT]++
}

END {
        for (t in T) {
                print t, T[t]
        }
}' tudberr

Output i got is


op                                       usr                                      description                              req                TMUnitTrou SUBTNode       Count
op=586988                                usr=80                                   description=Read                         req=serv=psts,TMUn TMUnitTrou SUBTNode=21,pt  6
                                                                                                                                                                         1
```

Comment: I would spend my time making the data easier to process. If you're lucky, you can get the generating system to make `|` separated columns. Delete any text descriptions that aren't data, and rely on column # to be the correct type of data, i.e. `tons=$1;op=$2;tag=$3;....`. All IMHO. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

As `shellter` said, "making your data easier to process":

```
awk '{ s=""; 
       j=0; 
       for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { if(index($i,"=")==0)
                                 {k[j]=k[j] FS $i } 
                              else k[++j]=$i; }; 
       for(i in k){ print i,k[i] } 
       delete k; print "" }' tudberr
```

This will output (for the first 3 lines of your input file):

```
0  Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]:
1 tons=1012
2 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER
3 tag=101
4 usr=80
5 nentries=0
6 description=Read usror on tonsection to target
7 req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp
8 filter=(objectClass=*)

0  Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]:
1 tons=1012
2 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER
3 tag=101
4 usr=80
5 nentries=0
6 description=Read usror on tonsection to target
7 req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp
8 filter=(objectClass=*)

0  Aug 25 17:21:39 DL_2_11 dpat[999]:
1 tons=1012
2 op=586988 RESERCH ANSWER
3 tag=101
4 usr=80
5 nentries=0
6 description=Read usror on tonsection to target
7 req=serv=psts,TMUnitTroup=10,cmsId=1234asdbfghueikjla5342789157b3,pu=multiple,SUBTNode=21,pt=pmp
8 filter=(objectClass=*)
```

This output should be easier to process...

Comment: Thanks Output look nice how about to convert it to column table after this output generation.

Comment: I did change my input data little bit as suggested by shelter

Comment: @iconluv: The output is generated by `for(i in k){ print i,k[i] }` you can change it any way you need, so if you need your data in column table, then you are free to change it...